# Asymptotic behavior of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{2^k}{k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, power-series

I'm looking for an asymptotic equivalent of

$$\sum_{0 < k \le n} \frac{2^k}{k}$$

as $n \to \infty$. A plausible candidate seems to be $\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}$ ([WolframAlpha plot](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D+2%5Ek%2Fk%29%2F%282%5E%7Bn%2B1%7D%2F%28n%2B1%29%29+for+n+from+1+to+100000&x=-1564&y=-71), and the intuitive similarity with $\sum_{k \le n} 2^k = 2^{n+1}$ is also appealing), but my usual tricks seem powerless here.

I've tried:

- Interpreting $x^k/k$ as the primitive of $x^{k-1}$ and setting $x=2$
- Replacing $2^k/k$ with $\int_{x=0}^2 x^{k-1}$
- Reordering the sum's terms to expose log-resembling sub-sums like $\sum_k 1/k$
- Finding lower and upper bounds asymptotically equivalent to $\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}$ -- the lower bound is easy ($\sum\limits_{k \le n}  \frac{2^k}{k} \ge \sum\limits_{k \le n} \frac{2^k}{n+1} \ge \frac{\sum\limits_{k \le n} 2^k}{n+1} \ge \frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}$), but the upper bound seems trickier (I couldn't think of a sequence $\varepsilon_k \in o(2^k/k)$ that would make it easy to estimate $\sum_{0 < k \le n} 2^k/k - \varepsilon_k$)
- ... and a few others, to no avail

Any hints?

Comment: I'd think interpreting this as a certain evaluation of a logarithm to be the soundest approach, since one can bring some tools from complex analysis to bear on such.

Comment: Call your sum $S_n$.  Let $T_n = S_n/2^n$; then it's not hard to show that $T_1 = 1$, $T_n = T_{n-1}/2 + 1/n$.  You want to show $T_n \sim 2/(n+1)$.  Not sure this helps.

Comment: You mean $1\leq k \leq n$.

Comment: In the limit as it goes to infinity we can sum the divergent series as $\ln(1 - 2) = \ln(-1) = i \pi$ but thats certainly not a convergent limit using the usual absolute value

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For every $n$, $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k2^k\geqslant\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1n2^k=\frac1n(2^{n+1}-1).$$
On the other hand, for every $u$ in $(0,1)$, $$S_n=\sum_{k\lt un}\frac1k2^k+\sum_{un\leqslant k\leqslant n}\frac1k2^k\leqslant\sum_{k\lt un}2^k+\sum_{un\leqslant k\leqslant n}\frac1{un}2^k\leqslant2^{un+1}+\frac1{un}2^{n+1}.$$ Thus,
$$
2-\frac1{2^n}\leqslant\frac{n}{2^n}S_n\leqslant\frac2u+\frac{2n}{2^{(1-u)n}}
$$ which implies $$2\leqslant\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}S_n\leqslant\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}S_n\leqslant\frac2u$$
This holds for every $u\lt1$ hence

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}S_n=2.$$

(Which confirms your intuition.)

Likewise, for every real number $\alpha$, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^\alpha}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^k}{k^\alpha}=2.$$
Likewise (bis), for every real number $x\gt1$ and every real number $\alpha$,

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^\alpha}{x^n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x^k}{k^\alpha}=\frac{x}{x-1}.$$

Comment: Thanks! I find the "This holds for every ... hence" line a bit confusing though :/ Once you multiply both sides by $n/2^n$ and look at $u \to 1$, doesn't the upper bound reduce to $2n+2$ instead of just $2+\varepsilon_n$? Or did I miss something?

Comment: Once one multiplies both sides by $n/2^n$ and one considers the limit $n\to\infty$, one sees that the limsup is at most $2/u$. This holds for every $u\lt1$ (no limit here) hence the limsup us $\leqslant2$, QED.

Comment: Alright, this makes a lot of sense. Very nice solution!

Answer (score 6):

The Euler-Maclaurin summation formula is useful for approximating sums and often reveals the asymptotic behavior with only a few terms.  This problem is an interesting application because the precise asymptotic behavior requires summing an infinite number of terms with Bernoulli numbers as coefficients  - the terms that are typically neglected.

Using the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula with $f(x) = 2^x/x$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^k}{k} = C+\int_{1}^{n}f(x)\,dx + \frac1{2}f(n)+\frac{B_2}{2!}f'(n) + \frac{B_4}{4!}f'''(n)+ \ldots.$$

The integral is the exponential integral which behaves asymptotically as $Ei(x) \sim e^x/x$ as $x \rightarrow \infty:$

$$\int_{1}^{n}f(x)\,dx=\int_{1}^{n}\frac{2^x}{x}\,dx= Ei(n\log2)-Ei(\log2) \sim \frac{e^{n\log 2}}{n\log 2}.$$

Taking the odd-order derivatives we find a pattern

$$f'(x) = \frac{2^x}{x}\left(\log2-\frac1{x}\right)\sim\frac{2^x}{x}\log2\\
f'''(x) = \frac{2^x}{x}\left[\left(\log2-\frac1{x}\right)^3+O(x^{-2})\right]\sim\frac{2^x}{x}(\log 2)^3\\ \ldots$$

Hence,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^k}{k} \sim \frac{2^n}{n}\left[\frac1{\log 2}+\frac1{2}+\frac1{\log 2}\left(\frac{B_2}{2!}(\log 2)^2 + \frac{B_4}{4!}(\log 2)^4+ \ldots\right)\right]\,\,(*)$$

The trailing terms can be summed exactly.  The generating function for the Bernoulli numbers is $x/(e^x-1)$ where

$$\frac{x}{e^x-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{B_kx^k}{k!}.$$

The first two Bernoulli numbers are $B_0 = 1$ and $B_1 = -1/2$.  They are zero for odd $n \geq 3$.

Hence,

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{B_k(\log 2)^k}{k!} = \frac{\log 2}{e^{\log 2}-1}-1 + \frac{\log 2}{2}= \log 2-1 + \frac{\log 2}{2}.$$

Substituting into $(*)$ we get

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^k}{k} \sim \frac{2^n}{n}\left[\frac1{\log 2}+\frac1{2}+\frac1{\log 2}\left(\log 2-1 + \frac{\log 2}{2}\right)\right]=\frac{2^n}{n}2,$$

and

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^k}{k} \sim \frac{2^{n+1}}{n}$$

Comment: Very interesting calculation. I'm accepting the simpler answer, but this is indeed an interesting case where the small trends add up. Nice one!

Answer (score 4):

If $u_n=\dfrac{2^n}n$, we have $u_{n+1}-u_n\sim\dfrac{2^n}n=u_n$.

As the serie $\sum u_n$ is nonnegative and diverges, we obtain by [Stolz-Cesàro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem):
$$S_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n u_k\sim \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n (u_{k+1}-u_k)=u_{n+1}-u_1\sim\frac{2^{n+1}}n.$$

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is correct, we have

$$\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2^k}{k}}{\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}} \to 1$$

indeed by Stolz-Cesaro

$$\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}=\frac{\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}}{\frac{2^{n+2}}{n+2}-\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2\frac{n+1}{n+2}-1}\to 1$$

Answer (score 1):

An asymptotic expansion for large $n$ may also be derived as follows:
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{2^k }}{k}} & = \frac{{2^n }}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\frac{{2^{ - k} }}{{1 - k/n}}}  = \frac{{2^n }}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {2^{ - k} \sum\limits_{j = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{k^j }}{{n^j }}} }  \sim \frac{{2^n }}{n}\sum\limits_{j = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^j }}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {k^j 2^{ - k} } } \\ & = \frac{{2^{n + 1} }}{n}\bigg( 1 + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {2^{j} A_j \!\left( {\tfrac{1}{2}} \right)\frac{1}{{n^j }}} \bigg)= \frac{{2^{n + 1} }}{n}\bigg( 1 + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {\frac{A_j (2)}{{n^j }}} \bigg).
\end{align*}
Here $A_j$ denotes the $j$th [Eulerian polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number). In terms of the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)
$$
A_j (2) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^j  k! \,S(j,k) .
$$
Thus,
$$\tag{1}
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{2^k }}{k}}  \sim \frac{{2^{n + 1} }}{n}\left( {1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{3}{{n^2 }} + \frac{{13}}{{n^3 }} + \frac{{75}}{{n^4 }} + \frac{{541}}{{n^5 }} +  \ldots } \right)
$$
as $n\to +\infty$. The numbers $1,3,13,75,541,\ldots$ are the [ordered Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number). It follows from their asymptotic behaviour that the best approximation coming from $(1)$ is achieved by taking only $
\left\lfloor n\log 2 \right\rfloor+1$ terms in the asymptotic series.

Answer (score 0):

We note that the average value of

$$\frac{2^k}{k}$$

is given by

$$ \frac{1}{n-1} \int_1^n{\frac{2^t}{t} dt}  = \frac{1}{n-1} \left[\operatorname{Ei}(n\log(2)) - some constant \right]  \approx \frac{1}{n-1} \operatorname{Ei}(n \log(2))$$

We note that $$e^{x\log(2)}$$ is asymptotically greater than $$\operatorname{Ei}(x\log(2))$$ but it appears that I cannot find a constant $c$ between $0$ and $1$ such that

$$e^{cx\log(2)}$$ is also asymptotically greater suggesting these two asymptotic classes may have a more intricate relationship than is apparent

For all intents and purposes $\frac{2^n}{n}$ is asymptotically equivalent. To find something that matches the difference of terms more closely will require heavier machinery

Comment: Side note: You seem to be using $n$ as both a bound variable under the integral, and unbound outside; that's somewhat confusing.

Comment: @Clément I understand intuitively that doing doesn't have any geometric interpretation, but I've never found a time when such a symbolic calculation has ever given me issues. Why is there so much opposition to doing so? It seems like a natural way to incorporate indefinite integration into the frame work of definite integrals

Comment: Well, you have a definite integral here. It looks a bit like writing $\forall x, \forall x, x-x=0$, which might be formally valid, but is still confusing.