# Is there any closed form expression for the following sum $\sum_{t=1}^T \frac{2^t}{t} = ?$

Tags: summation

Is the result upper bounded by $E_i(\ln(2)T)$ ?

Edit: where $$E_i(y) = \int_{-\infty}^y \frac{\exp(z)}{z} \mathbb{dz}$$

Comment: What's $E_i$ in your expression?

Comment: Would a summation by parts work?

Comment: @jdods I didn't get. Please reply with your expression. Thanks!

Comment: Look up summation by parts or Newton summation. There are formula for finite sums where the summand is the product of sequences which have nice finite sum formula.

Comment: There is a "closed form" involving the incomplete Beta function $- B(2; n+1,0) - i\pi$

Comment: What is $n$ ? Also the sum must be in $\mathbb{R}$ right ?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the main contribute of $\sum_{t=1}^{T}\frac{2^t}{t}$ comes from the last terms, and

$$\sum_{t=1}^{T}\frac{2^t}{t} = \frac{2^T}{T}\sum_{t=0}^{T-1}\frac{1}{2^{t}(1-\frac{t}{T})}\geq\frac{2^T}{T}\sum_{t=0}^{T-1}\frac{1+\frac{t}{T}}{2^t}=\frac{2^{T+1}}{T}\left(1+\frac{1}{T}+O(2^{-T})\right). $$
To approximate the sum with an integral is another good way to go.