# Limit of a finite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, summation

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence defined by $$a_n = \frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2^k}{k}\right)$$

Show that the sequence converges and find its limit.

**Update**: After some computation I see that its limit is 1. Maybe we can use the "squeeze" theorem? I proved that $a_n > 1, \forall n \geq 2$ but I can't find the upper bound.
I appreciate all help. Thank you

Comment: Have you considered using the Monotone Convergence Theorem?

Comment: I've considered it, but after that I can't find any relation between $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ that doesn't involve $n$. Therefore no solution for its limit (that's what I think).

Comment: Look what I used, do you know this property of diverging series of positive terms? It's often very useful when the general term is of this type.

Comment: At class we don't study much about diverging series. That's a nice property! Thanks a lot!

Comment: it's really easy to prove , you just have to use :
$u_n$ ~ $v_n$ <=> $ u_n = v_n +o(v_n) $ You translate this into inequality with an $\epsilon$ : $ u_n - v_n \leq \epsilon*v_n $ for n>N, a certain integer. You sum this from N to n, and you can conclude. It's very useful

Comment: Approximate your sum using the [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral), then see the section on “asymptotics”.

Comment: Intuitively, it seems reasonable to say that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2^k}{k}$ is in the [order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2^k}{n/2}$, but a rigorous proof escapes me.

Comment: See here for answer, including Euler-Maclaurin along the lines of @Lucian's suggestion:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888354/asymptotic-behavior-of-sum-limits-k-1n-frac2kk/888704#888704

Comment: @lucian, that's essentially what I have proved. But it uses few material, like I said to primitiveroot, you only use the definition of $a_n$ ~ $b_n$ and the fact that $\sum a_n$ diverges is the same as : $(\sum a_n) \rightarrow +\infty $. I'll add the proof in my answer

Answer (score 2):

I've got an interesting solution I think, it uses partial sums of diverging series with positive terms:

Let: $b_n = \frac{2^n}{n}$ ; $v_n = b_{n}-b_{n-1}$

$ v_n = \frac{2^n}{n}-\frac{2^{n-1}}{n-1} = \frac{2^{n-1}}{n-1}*[ 1-\frac{2}{n} ] $ ~ $ \frac{2^{n-1}}{n-1} = b_{n-1}$ ,  when $ n \rightarrow +\infty $

$(b_n) \rightarrow +\infty $, when $n \rightarrow +\infty$ , so $\sum v_n$ diverges and we can say that both partial sums are equivalent:

$ \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} v_k = b_{n+1}-b_1 $ ~ $b_{n+1}$ ~ $ \sum_{k=1}^n b_k $ , when $ n \rightarrow +\infty $

Hence you get: $ a_n = \frac{1}{b_{n+1}}*\sum_{k=1}^n b_k $ ~ 1 , when $ n \rightarrow +\infty $

You get the limit :) , which is 1 like you said

**Edit:** I'll prove the property I used above. Let's have $ \sum u_n$ and $\sum v_n  $ two diverging series of positive terms: $ u_n,v_n \geq 0 $ such as: $u_n$ ~ $v_n$

$u_n$ ~ $v_n$ <=> $ u_n = v_n + o(v_n) $

$ u_n = v_n + o(v_n) $ <=> for any $ \epsilon > 0 , n \geq N => u_n -v_n \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}*v_n $

Now we sum this from N+1 to n :

$ \sum_{k =N+1}^n u_k -\sum_{k =N+1}^n v_k \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}*\sum_{k =N+1}^n v_k $

=> $ \sum_{k =1}^n u_k -\sum_{k =1}^n v_k \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}*\sum_{k =1}^n v_k + \sum_{k =1}^N u_k -(\frac{\epsilon}{2} +1)*\sum_{k =1}^N v_k $

=> $ \sum_{k =1}^n u_k -\sum_{k =1}^n v_k \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}*\sum_{k =1}^n v_k + \sum_{k =1}^N u_k $ , since $ (\frac{\epsilon}{2} +1)*\sum_{k =1}^N v_k \geq 0  $

Now I'll define : $U_n = \sum_{k =1}^n u_k$, $ V_n = \sum_{k =1}^n v_k $

The hypothesis is : $(V_n) \rightarrow +\infty$ ; so : $ \sum_{k =1}^N u_k =o(V_n) $

=> $ \epsilon > 0 , n \geq N_o => \sum_{k =1}^N u_k \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}*\sum_{k =1}^n v_k  $

You get :  $ \epsilon >0 , n > max(N, N_o) => U_n -V_n \leq \epsilon*V_n $

That's exactly : $ U_n -V_n = o(V_n) $ ie $U_n$ ~ $V_n$

Answer (score 2):

By Stoltz-Cesaro

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2^k}{k}}{\frac{2^{n+1}} {n+1}}$$

we obtain

$$\frac{\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}}{\frac{2^{n+2}}{n+2}-\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}}=\frac1{\frac{2(n+1)}{n+2}-1}\to 1$$

Refer to the related

- [Finding $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{n}{a^{n+1}}\left(a+\frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{a^3}{3}+\cdots+\frac{a^n}{n}\right)}$ where $a>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3454372/505767)

Comment: This is basically a copy-paste of your previous answer, and would probably be better as a comment.

Comment: @ArnaudD. This is not a copy paste, I've indeed write down all the solution and also indicated the general case as related. I'm wondering how is possible that this simple derivation wasn't already indicated as answer.

Answer (score 1):

After the change of summation index $j:=n+1-k$, we obtain that
$$a_n=\sum_{j=1}^n2^{-j}+\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{j2^{-j}}{n+1-j}.$$
Define $$b_n:=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{j2^{-j}}{n+1-j}$$
and fix $R\geqslant 1$. Denote $I_R:=\{j\mid n+1-j\geqslant R\}$ and $J_R:=\{j\leqslant n\mid n+1-j\lt R\}$. Since 
$$\sum_{j\in I_R}\frac{j2^{-j}}{n+1-j}\leqslant \frac 1R\sum_{j=1}^\infty j2^{-j},\mbox{ and }$$
$$\sum_{j\in J_R}\frac{j2^{-j}}{n+1-j}\leqslant\sum_{j\in J_R}j2^{-j}\leqslant n2^{-(n+1-R)}=n2^{-n}2^{R-1},$$
we get 
$$0\leqslant b_n=\sum_{j\in I_R}\frac{j2^{-j}}{n+1-j}+\sum_{j\in J_R}\frac{j2^{-j}}{n+1-j}\leqslant \frac 1R\sum_{j=1}^\infty j2^{-j}+n2^{-n}2^{R-1}.$$