# Finding $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{n}{a^{n+1}}\left(a+\frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{a^3}{3}+\cdots+\frac{a^n}{n}\right)}$ where $a>1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

> $$\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim{\frac{n}{a^{n+1}}\left(a+\frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{a^3}{3}+\cdots+\frac{a^n}{n}\right)}=?, \;\;a>1$$

In Shaum's *Mathematical handbook of formulas and table*s I've seen:
$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots\;,x\in\langle-1,1]\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\ln{\Bigg(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\Bigg)}=1+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}+\frac{x^7}{7}+\cdots\;\;\;,x\in\langle-1,1\rangle$$
The term in parentheses reminded me of the harmonic series. I thought of using the Taylor series. Is that a good idea?
It says $a>0$ so I probably can't use these two formulas.
On the other hand:
$$e^x=x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots\;\;\;\;\;\;,$$
but there are no factorials in the denominators.

Source in Croatian: 2.kolokvij, matematička analiza

Comment: Shouldn't $$ln(1-x)=-\left(x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{4}+...\right)$$

Comment: One problem with this is the series does not converge for the values of $a$ we're concerned about $(a>1)$.

Comment: Look at $\frac{a^n}n+\frac{a^{n-1}}{n-1}+\cdots$ as $\frac{a^n}n\left(1+\frac{n}{n-1}\frac1a+\frac{n}{n-2}\frac1{a^2}+\cdots\right)$

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009105/limit-of-a-finite-sum) is almost a particular case, maybe it could help.

Comment: @ArnaudD. thank you! I will analyze it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{a^{n+1}}\left(a+\frac{a^2}2+\cdots+\frac{a^n}n\right)
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1a+\frac{n}{n-1}\frac1{a^2}+\frac{n}{n-2}\frac1{a^3}+\cdots\right)\tag1\\
&=\frac1a+\frac1{a^2}+\frac1{a^3}+\cdots\tag2\\
&=\frac1{a-1}\tag3
\end{align}
$$
The series on the right side of $(1)$ is dominated by
$$
\frac1a+\frac2{a^2}+\frac3{a^3}+\cdots=\frac{a}{(a-1)^2}\tag4
$$
which validates $(2)$.

Comment: Thank you for your approach! It is really elegant to look in the opposite direction.

Comment: @VerkhotsevaKatya: when $a\gt1$, those terms are larger. It's always best to start with the major terms.

Comment: I don't understand why the domination of (1) by (4) proves (2). Could someone explain me?

Comment: @Jeanba: This follows from the [discrete version of the Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/585319).

Comment: Thanks for answering! I still don't see from the formula what N and $f_N(n)$  are exactly here. $$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f_N(n)$$ can $N$ depends on $n$? I'm a bit lost, sorry if this is super easy.

Comment: @Jeanba: Since $N$ appears outside of the scope of $n$ (which is only defined inside the summation), $N$ cannot depend on $n$.

Comment: @Jeanba: the limit in this question is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{n}{n-k+1}\frac{[1\le k\le n]}{a^k}$ where $[\dots]$ are [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). Does that help?

Answer (score 8):

By Stoltz-Cesaro

$$\frac{n}{a^{n+1}}\left(a+\frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{a^3}{3}+…+\frac{a^n}{n}\right)=\frac{\left(a+\frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{a^3}{3}+…+\frac{a^n}{n}\right)}{\frac{a^{n+1}}{n}}$$

we obtain

$$\frac{\frac{a^{n+1}}{n}}{\frac{a^{n+2}}{n+1}-\frac{a^{n+1}}{n}}=\frac1{\frac{na}{n+1}-1} \to \frac1{a-1}$$

Comment: Is the last limit correct? It would look like the limit should be $1/(a-1)$. But using Stolz–Cesàro is a good idea!

Comment: @user Thank you very much! Is there any literature you could recommend on this topic?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Opsss yes of course! I fix it

Comment: @VerkhotsevaKatya Simply refer to [Stoltz-Cesaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) theorem.