# Finite summation closed form of power divided by linear

Tags: integration, summation

I have a finite sum:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^{k}}{k}$$

I am wondering how to write it in closed form.

I tried this, where I will plug in $x=2$ at the end:

$$f(x):=\sum_{k=1}^nx^{k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k=\frac{1-x^{n-1}}{1-x}$$

Integrate:

$$\int f(x)\,dx=\sum_{k=1}^n\int x^{k-1}dx=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x^k}{k}$$

but when I try to integrate $f(x)$, I am not able to reach a closed form, i.e. I get a long and convoluted sum...

Thank you!

Comment: Your value for the sum which appears after "f(x):=" is off. For $n=1$ the sum should be $1$ but the expression you give for $n=1$ gives $0.$ I think the exponent in the numerator should be $n$ rather than your $n-1.$

Comment: @coffeemath it's like that on purpose so that at end of the integration i get a summation starting at k=1 with x^k.

Comment: Look at the three expressions you have put after $f(x):=$ and make $n=1$ in each of the three expressions. They are *not* the same.

Comment: I don't think there is a closed form (at least without using special functions) for this sum, but you estimate the behaviour for large $n$ like in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/888354/399263

Comment: @zwim ok, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sum can be represented in terms of [Lerch zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^k}{k}=-\pi i-2^n\ \text{LerchPhi}(2,1,n)+\frac{2^n}{n}$$

Comment: Your $2^n \text{LerchPhi}(2,1,n)=\text B_2(n,0)$ with [this Incomplete Beta function result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+2%5En+lerchphi%282%2C1%2Cn%29%2Fbeta%282%2Cn%2C0%29)

Comment: How do you define $\Phi$ on the branch-cut? Can you prove this representation?

Answer (score 1):

It has no simple closed form, but its asymptotic evaluation is pretty straightfoward:

$$ S(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^k}{k} = \frac{2^n}{n}+2^n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k 2^{n-k}}=\frac{2^n}{n}+2^n[x^n]\left(\sum_{a\geq 1}\frac{x^a}{a}\sum_{b\geq 1}\frac{x^b}{2^b}\right)$$
hence

$$ S(n)=\frac{2^n}{n}+2^n [x^n]\left(-\log(1-x)\frac{x}{2-x}\right)=\frac{2^n}{n}+\frac{2^n}{2\pi i}\oint_{|x|=1-\varepsilon}\frac{-\log(1-x)}{(2-x)x^n}\,dx $$

or

$$ S(n)=\frac{2^n}{n}+2^n\operatorname*{Res}_{x=0}\frac{-\log(1-x)}{(2-x)x^{n+1}}. $$
Even without such representation, by Cesaro-Stolz

$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{S(n)}{2^n/n} = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{S(n+1)-S(n)}{2^{n+1}/(n+1)-2^n/n}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{2^{n+1}/(n+1)}{2^{(n+1)}/(n+1)-2^n/n}=2 $$
and the other terms of the asymptotic expansion can be reconstructed in a similar fashion.