# What is the asymptotics of $\sum_{k=0}^{\log\log n-1}\frac{\log n}{2^k(\log\log n-k)}$?

Tags: summation, asymptotics

Consider
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\log\log n-1}\frac{\log n}{2^k(\log\log n-k)}$$
What is the big-O value of this expression?

I think the answer is $O(\frac{\log n}{\log\log n})$. For this reason I partitioned it into:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{\log\log n}{2}-1}\frac{\log n}{k2^k}+\sum_{k=\frac{\log\log n}{2}}^{{\log\log n}-1}\frac{\log n}{k2^k}$$
Obviously, the left side is $O(\frac{\log n}{\log\log n})$ but I can't show that
$\sum_{k=\frac{\log\log n}{2}}^{{\log\log n}-1}\frac{\log n}{k2^k}=O(\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}).$

Comment: Sometimes it is helpful to write $S=\sum a^k / k$ and consider $dS/da$ which should be a geometric progression.

Answer (score 1):

By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4463181) answer of mine,
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{m - 1} {\frac{1}{{2^k (m - k)}}}  = 2^{ - m} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{m - 1} {\frac{{2^{m - k} }}{{m - k}}}  = 2^{ - m} \sum\limits_{k = 1}^m {\frac{{2^k }}{k}}  \sim \frac{2}{m}\left( {1 + \frac{1}{m} + \frac{3}{{m^2 }} + \frac{{13}}{{m^3 }} +  \ldots } \right)
$$
for large $m$. Thus
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\log \log n - 1} {\frac{{\log n}}{{2^k (\log \log n - k)}}}  \sim \frac{{2\log n}}{{\log \log n}}\left( {1 + \frac{1}{{\log \log n}} + \frac{3}{{(\log \log n)^2 }} + \frac{{13}}{{(\log \log n)^3 }} +  \ldots } \right)
$$
for large $n$.

Comment: Can you exlpain why$$ 2^{ - m} \sum\limits_{k = 1}^m {\frac{{2^k }}{k}}  \sim \frac{2}{m}\left( {1 + \frac{1}{m} + \frac{3}{{m^2 }} + \frac{{13}}{{m^3 }} +  \ldots } \right)$$?

Comment: There is a hyperlink on the word "this", just click on it. The answer is there.